# Stripe iOS, build configuration warning

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

When I build my iOS app that uses Stripe and run it I get this message:

> ⚠️ Warning! You're building your app in a non-debug configuration, but appear to be using your Stripe test key. Make sure not to submit to the App Store with your test keys!⚠️

I am using the DEBUG scheme which uses the xCode DEBUG configuration to my understanding.

What am I missing to get this right and avoid getting this warning?

Comment: if you got answer for this plz share.

Comment: I have not. I will if I do.

Comment: Nearly a year after this question was first asked and I am also receiving this warning although I am running in debug mode as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this. My guess is that you are using a prebuilt framework (perhaps via Carthage)? This warning is generated when Stripe detects that **it** wasn't compiled in the `Debug` configuration even though it's using a test key. If you are using a prebuilt framework, then it would be compiled in the `Release` configuration, regardless of what configuration you are using for your app's build.

If this is the case, then it's just a red herring.